# Is javascript asynchronous function internally designed using settimeout, setintervals etc?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

Is javascript asynchronous function internally designed using settimeout function?

since javscript language is based on single threaded, it depends on the event-loop which is supported by the browser or task queue or something to create asynchronous function.

so is settimeout function only the way to make asynchronous function in javascript?

Comment: in core JS yes, but hosts can provide other means like ajax.

Comment: No. It's not the only way. You can also use `Promise.resolve().then(() => youMethod());`. But I guess it's a bit less readable than using `setTimeout`

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your advice, can I ask one more question? 

when using ajax, javascript new xmlhttprequest object has to be created, and .onreadystatechange methods like something operates with the callback eventhandler. so is that event, like .onreadystatechange method designed internally with the timer function..?

Comment: @Lewis thanks for your answer. Ah, maybe my question is a bit of obscure. sorry. I`m using Promise in my nodejs sequelize project. 

what i am wondering is if that Promise library(whatever supports the asynchronous function) is bulit of javascript timer function internally.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the async of both timers and Promises are handled at lower level, probably written in C++.

Comment: some promise polyfills use setTimeout. ajax uses lower-level system calls that interrupt the loop w/o timers

Comment: @dandavis and Lewis thanks both of you. it was my big mistake to misunderstand that functions with [native code] also built with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage of separate processes you can use Web Workers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) if they are supported by your target browsers.

I.E:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
var first = document.querySelector('#number1');
var second = document.querySelector('#number2');

first.onchange = function() {
  myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
}
```

Another possibility is to use function* like redux-saga does.